# Google Cloud endpoints migrating to V2 : Execution failed for task ':backend:endpointsDiscoveryDocs'

Tags: java, android-studio, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I've completed the migration of a few projects in Android Studio 3 as instructed in the [official guide](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/legacy/v1/java/migrating), but I'm getting an error when trying to run the `endpointsDiscoveryDocs` target on gradle on an App Engine Endpoints backend module.

The error is a nested `NoClassDefFound` initializing `GenClientLibAction`:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   com.google.api.server.spi.tools.GenClientLibAction

This is my settings file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin:1.0.2'
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:1.3.3'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
//apply plugin: 'appengine'
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine'  // App Engine tasks
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.endpoints-framework-server'


sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

dependencies {
    //appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.54'
    providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'servlet-api', version:'2.5'


    compile 'com.google.endpoints:endpoints-framework:2.0.8'
    compile 'com.google.endpoints:endpoints-framework-tools:2.0.8'

    compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'


    implementation 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:5.1.17'
    implementation 'com.ganyo:gcm-server:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-server-sdk:3.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.appengine.tools:appengine-gcs-client:0.6'

}
endpointsServer {
    // Endpoints Framework Plugin server-side configuration
    hostname = "libre-gluten.appspot.com"
}
```

The stack is as follows

> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task
>   ':backend:endpointsDiscoveryDocs'.
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipCachedTaskExecuter.execute(SkipCachedTaskExecuter.java:106)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBuildCacheKeyExecuter.execute(ResolveBuildCacheKeyExecuter.java:60)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
>         at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>         at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>         at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.api.server.spi.tools.GenClientLibAction
>         at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.EndpointsTool.(EndpointsTool.java:55)
>         at com.google.cloud.tools.gradle.endpoints.framework.server.task.GenerateDiscoveryDocsTask.generateDiscoveryDocs(GenerateDiscoveryDocsTask.java:137)
>         at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:141)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:731)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:705)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
>         ... 29 more

There is already an [open issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin/issues/52) in the project Github, but there's no feedback from the project owners.

I have several project on halt because of this issue, has someone encountered this, any idea on how to fix this error?